# Microsoft Teams Bot not forgetting credentials after logout

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am having some issues with my Teams Bot on calling "Logout".
The bot is build using node.js

It seems to be signing out correctly by calling await botAdapter.signOutUser(context, this.connectionName).

However, upon "Login" it will attempt to sign in using previous input credentials. In this scenario, the user logged in to account "TEST1" but want to log out and then log in with "TEST2", but the Teams Bot will continously retry login as "TEST1".

Am I missing to configure something or call another command for clearing cache on this?

Comment: Hi @T-Rex, we are testing your scenario practically, we will update you soon.

Comment: Thank you Jagadeesh, I appreciate that very much. Let me know what you find out.

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT Hello Jagadeesh, just wanted to chime in and check if there are any news yet on this?

Comment: Hi @T-Rex, we are unable to repro issue , please share the document/sample that you are following , so that we can understand where exactly issue is.

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT Hello Jagadeesh, I understand. Do you have a preferred way of received a zip file of my Teams Bot project (node.js)?

Comment: Hi @T-Rex, you can share through github

Comment: Hello @Jagadeesh-MSFT, the project contains some sensitive data, perhaps another approach? Also, the login flow is using the bot samples for WaterfallDialog login steps, I was thinking if perhaps the login/logout issues could be related to the Oauth setup in the Web App Bot we have hosted on Azure and not the actual code? I have set up the Web App Bot channel using Oauth 2 Generic Provider, connecting to our Auth0 endpoint for authentication flow. The "Test Connection" is instant response and responds "Test Connection to 'JobMonitorTeamsBotAuth0Ext' Succeeded" with the expected access token.

Comment: @T-Rex, How you are doing login if you are using the current teams-auth sample developed in waterfall dialogs. it has the logout implementation as well, but if you are logging out once it has SSO implementation it will not ask for any further credentials also. the best thing is to clear your session once you perform logout that will help

Comment: Hello @Trinetra-MSFT, how am I supposed to do this for the nodejs in mainDialog? I read the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#delete-data but I could not seem to make it work from within the mainDialog, I am trying to set it up to be triggered when user input is "logout"

Comment: Hello @Trinetra-MSFT, how am I supposed to do this for the nodejs in mainDialog? I read the documentation here learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/bot-service/… but I could not seem to make it work from within the mainDialog, I am trying to set it up to be triggered when user input is "logout"

Comment: @T-Rex- Could you please take a look at [Sample code here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth/Dialogs/LogoutDialog.cs#L47)?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Thank you for your response. I used the nodejs/46.teams-auth sample as base for my project, so it has that same logic for logout as well.

Comment: @T-Rex - I tried the node sample and it asks me to pick an account evey time I logout and try to login (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQGaN.png). Could you please confirm if you are using [SSO for Bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots)?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I am not using Azure AD SSO, as mentioned in a previous comment "I have set up the Web App Bot channel using Oauth 2 Generic Provider, connecting to our Auth0 endpoint for authentication flow."

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share your manifest so that I can try the same at my end?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Sure! Hopefully it can help finding a solution: https://cs258969a0fd8fcx43fbxba9.blob.core.windows.net/temp/manifest.json

Comment: Thanks for sharing the manifest. Seems like your OAuth provider is stateful and after signout, calling signin automatically signs in their bot user. That's by design. we dont notify the OAuth provider on signout.

Comment: Thank you Wajeed, I have resolved it now

Answer (score 0):

*Note: Adding Answer for comments for visibility*

Seems like your OAuth provider is stateful and after signout, calling signin automatically signs in their bot user. That's by design. we dont notify the OAuth provider on signout.